# This expression is not callable. Type 'Boolean' has no call signatures

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I started to study a new stack of technologies and, as it should be, study new errors.

But there is one type of error that haunts me. And I'm not sure if I'm doing the right thing with this.

For example, I get this error for all Vue components:

> Property 'focused' does not exist on type '{ onInput(event: any): void; focus(): void; blur(): void; }'. Did you mean 'focus'?

```
blur(): void {
  this.focused = false
}
```

I solve this error in a similar way:

```
blur(): void {
  (this as any).focused = false
}
```

But I'm confused that I need to do this absolutely everywhere and in every component.

And I don't know how to solve the following error at all:

> This expression is not callable.
> Type 'Boolean' has no call signatures.

```
blur(): void {
  (this as any).l.focused = false
}
```

Swears at "false".

`data()` code:

```
data(): any {
  return {
    l: {
      focused: false
    }
  }
},
```

Can you please tell me how to format the code correctly in such cases?

Answer (score 1):

> To let TypeScript properly infer types inside Vue component options, you need to define components with Vue.component or Vue.extend:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Basic-Usage

Comment: In Vue 3, we have to use defineComponent ? am i right ?

Comment: @hackwithharsha Yes, the Vue 3 docs say that. But Nuxt doesn't support Vue 3 right now. But for Vue 2 personally, I used Vue.extend when using the composition api.